# Firefox History had gone

Tags: firefox, database, places.sqlite

I have a similar problem of this thread:

[How do I repair a corrupted Firefox places.sqlite database?](https://superuser.com/questions/111998/how-do-i-repair-a-corrupted-firefox-places-sqlite-database)

I would make a comment there to explain my problem, rather than create a new thread. Unfortunately, system said I need to have 50 reputation to make a comment. So, my way was to create a new thread.

After make a dump.sql and searched for "ERROR:" line, I found it just following a "moz_places" collumn. Running the next step, "SELECT id FROM moz_places WHERE id >= 514500;", prompt replyed to me just "Error: database disk image is malformed", no matter what id I put, even "1" or "2".

Running sqlite3_analyze, I get this:

```
ERROR: database disk image is malformed
database disk image is malformed
    while executing
"db eval {CREATE TEMP TABLE dbstat AS SELECT * FROM temp.stat
         ORDER BY name, path}"
```

Running "PRAGMA integrity_check;", I got this:

```
*** in database main ***
Page 7577: btreeInitPage() returns error code 11
Page 7205: btreeInitPage() returns error code 11
...
Page 6383: btreeInitPage() returns error code 11
On tree page 14 cell 5: Child page depth differs
...
Page 1868 is never used
```

(...) means many lines with different parameters.

Firefox is running fine, but History had gone.
And browser stops to make new entries for sites I visit.
At History screen, there are only few entries (3 or 4) for sites visited, but "folders" like "today", "yesterday", "1 week ago" are still there, but empty.

I suspect, it isn't hard to recover my places.sqlite if I wasn't so newbie with SQLite. So, I ask for suggestions and ideas.

More informations:
File places.sqlite is about 40 Mb.

Favorites looks OK, but I cannot export as HTML or make a backup.
Nothing happens if I try to do it.
But they are there, appearing at menu.

Comment: Your question being? Just delete the file and Firefox will recreate it. Be warned though, it also contains the Bookmarks. If you cannot export them, you’ll have to save them manually.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. Problem is I need that History records. Thus, I'll try any workaround to recover it. BTW, how to save Bookmark manually? One by one?

Comment: I agree that getting it recovered would be great. However, I believe this is a hopeless endeavor that you shouldn’t spend too much time on. On my Mac, I can select an entire folder’s contents and copy them. Either way, you should stop using the database to avoid further corruption.