# Firefox v55 - broken places.sqlite compatibility?

Tags: firefox

I've got a "corrupt places.sqlite" problem immediately after upgrading to Firefox v55; I've tried repairing this file by dumping it and importing data into a newly created file, but Firefox marks the new file as corrupt as well.
Is this a problem in the version 55 of Firefox?

Comment: A few things that might be useful: 1) There wasn't a problem specific to V55, but places.sqlite can get corrupted for a variety of reasons.  2) There are some resources to repair it.  A previous question here is pretty comprehensive: [How do I repair a corrupted Firefox places.sqlite database?](https://superuser.com/questions/111998/how-do-i-repair-a-corrupted-firefox-places-sqlite-database).  Another resource from Mozilla: [places.sqlite Database Troubleshooting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Places/places.sqlite_Database_Troubleshooting).